# Django: How to Order a set By the number of its children's children?

Tags: python, django

So I have two many-to-one relationships `(Parent -> Child -> SubChild)`, and I want to order the Parents by the number of subchildren they have.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this elegantly. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
parents = Parent.objects.all()

parents_map = {}

for p in parents:
    total = 0
    children = Child.objects.filter(parent=p)
    for c in children:
        total += Subchildren.objects.filter(child=c).count()

    parents_map[p] = total

# sort the dict into a list of tuples
parents_list = sorted(parents_map.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

parents = []

for p in parents_list:
    parents.append(p[0])

return parents
```

It works, but I want to know: is there is a better/faster/more elegant way to do this?

EDIT: Question was simplified for generalization purposes, but what I need is actually is to sort of parents by the count of the sub-sub-children, in case this affects your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Define a subchildren_count in the Parent class:

```
class Parent(models.Model):

    @property
    def subchildren_count(self):
        return Subchildren.objects.filter(child__parent=self).count()
```

And then order them by that property

Comment: This worked beautifully! It even works for multiple levels of subchildren: `SubSubChildren.objects.filter(subchild__child__parent=self)`

Comment: Note: To sort these, you cannot use `order_by` on the property. You have to use `sorted(Parent.objects.all(), key=lambda a: a.subchildren_count)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can get the parent list ordered by their subchildren count with just an statement and without having to use 'sorted' function.
Asumming the ForeignKey field (to Parent) in Child model class has a related_name of 'children', and that the ForeignKey field (to Child) in SubChild model class has a related_name of 'subchildren', this is the proper statement:

```
return Parent.objects.all().annotate(
         count_subchildren=Count('children__subchildren')
       ).order_by('-count_subchildren')
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Better answer than mine